# Does Python have anything like Java's System.arraycopy?

Tags: java, python

Does Python have anything like Java's System.arraycopy? I don't want to just copy the reference (shallow copy) nor do I want to slice it (deep copy w/new ref).  I want to keep the target's reference (as I have multiple variables pointing to the same list) and copy the individual cells from the source to the target.  Exactly like Java's arraycopy.  So far the only way I can find to do this in Python is to write my own.  In Java it is more performant to use System.arraycopy than rolling your own, not sure if that is the case in Python.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I follow the described behavior, slice assignment is the Pythonic way to do this:

```
foo = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
bar = foo
baz = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
foo[0:4] = baz[0:4]

>>> foo
[10, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> bar
[10, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If the source contains object references, that will assign references to the same objects into the destination - if you want to deep copy the source data I think you'd have to do something like:

```
foo[0:4] = [copy.deepcopy(x) for x in baz[0:4]]
```

Comment: do you really need deepcopy() here? couldn't it be done simply as `foo[0:4] = [x for x in baz[0:4]]`

Comment: In Python 3, range returns a lazy sequence object - it does not return a list. so need to convert foo to a list as `foo = list(range(10))`. 
else it throws an error `TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: True! The example is from Python 2 days - slice assignment works the same, but it's probably clearer now if I write out the example lists as literals.

Comment: As for whether you need deepcopy or not - it depends what the contents of your list are! You wouldn't want to do the list comprehension as your first comment shows it, in that case slice assignment is better. But if your list contains mutable objects, you'll care a lot about whether you've copied the _contents_ of those objects or just a reference to the original! And either slice assignment or the list comprehension copy the references rather than the contents.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Peter DeGlopper's method is way better. Go for that one.

Sorry, this is the best you get:

```
def arrayCopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length):
    for i in range(length):
        dest[i + destPos] = src[i + srcPos]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def array_copy(src: bytes, src_pos: int, dest: bytes, dest_pos: int, length: int) -> bytes:
return dest[:dest_pos]+src[src_pos:length]+dest[dest_pos+length:]
```

Answer (score 0):

If in case you are using a byte-like object (which support buffer protocol), in that case you can use `memoryview`

```
k = [3, 4, 1, 1, 9, 7, 6]
bk = bytearray(k)
mk = memoryview(bk)
mk.obj
mk[3:5] = b"hu"
mk.obj
```

this allows for faster mutations.
read more: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview